# When is the best time to commit child fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

There is lack of information about nested `Fragments` in the web, so here is my question.

Since child fragments can be added only dynamically, what is the best place to do this and why? I mean what is best callback to perform this operation:`onCreate()`,`onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, etc.?

**EDIT**: 
I just tested it and it seems there is no difference, it's possible to commit child fragments even in `onAttach()` callback of parent fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on intuition and the general idea about the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle). I'd say you can safely do it in `onCreateView()`. But I'd test this a little if I was you. Embeded fragments should still be managed by the activity so I'm pretty sure it should be possible to do it earlier like in `onCreate()` or `onAttach()`.

Comment: Good idea and it works from `onCreateView` on Android 2.2, but how parent finds out container view for commit if parent knows nothing about it's view while in `onCreateView()`? What do you think about it? Maybe it's better to use `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: I'd use onCreateView(). That is my favored place. And you are right if you are going to put the views inside views of the parent fragment that won't work. But if you use fragments without views that won't be an issue and you'd probably be able to create the fragments anywhere during the lifecycle of a fragment.

Comment: Actually it's very strange but it works from `onCreateView` even if child fragment has visible part...o_O